# Sorting array in date order and displaying array values in table view with section

Tags: swift, sorting

this is my model class

```
class Messages: NSObject {

    var id: Int?
    var sender_id: Int?
    var group_id: Int?
    var message_type: Int?
    var message: String?
    var sent_time: Date?
    var status: Int?

    init(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) {
         super.init()

        self.id = (dictionary["id"] as! NSString).integerValue
        self.sender_id = (dictionary["sender_id"] as! NSString).integerValue
        self.group_id = (dictionary["group_id"] as! NSString).integerValue
        self.message_type = (dictionary["message_type"] as! NSString).integerValue
        self.message = dictionary["message"] as! String?
        let inputTime = dictionary["sent_time"] as! String?
        let inputDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        let inputTimeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
        inputDateFormatter.timeZone = inputTimeZone
        inputDateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        let dateFromString = inputDateFormatter.date(from: inputTime!)
        self.sent_time = dateFromString
        self.status = (dictionary["status"] as! NSString).integerValue

    }


}
```

this is my model class object array

```
var messages = [Messages]()
```

the array is sort a ascending order

```
self.messages.sort(by: { $0.sent_time! < $1.sent_time! })
```

how to create the different arrays for day wise and this array is store in dictionary and view in table view with section title foe day

look like this

[image]

Comment: What is the purpose of this interesting syntax: `as! String?`? And why are all properties declared as optionals but most of them are initialized as non-optional?

Comment: no  but i have only one array for message class object

Comment: create different array for section wise

Comment: e.g.  var today  = GroupMessage(time: "Today", array: [Messages])        var yesterday = GroupMessage(time: "YesterDay"), array:[Messages])  this is my static code